# Is US7103906 a valid patent?

Tags: prior-art-request, us7103906

It was recently used in litigation against Netflix, but I don't think that has been resolved yet. It feels like there ought to be prior art related to this functionality.

Comment: Do you think the 2 media protocols for device 1 and device 2 need to be different from each other according to the patent?

Comment: I don't see why it would have to be, based on how the patent is worded

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this patent was indeed rule invalid:
https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20150716881